# HealthKit HKQuery from creation date

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I am syncing weight data from HealthKit and I keep a reference to the latest weight data synced which I use to retrieve HealthKit data like this:

```
let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(latestSyncDate, endDate:NSDate(), options: .None)
```

The problem with this approach is when the user enters historic data which will not be synced. How do I perform the same query but with CreationDate (instead of StartDate), or some kind of database ID which will identify the historic value as being newer?

I just want to filter out all the newly created values from healthkit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'd like synchronize data from HealthKit, check out [HKAnchoredObjectQuery](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKAnchoredObjectQuery_Class/). Each time you query with `HKAnchoredObjectQuery`, you'll get only the samples that have been added or deleted since the last time you queried.